# Differences in w.write between Python 3.2 and 2.6?

Tags: python, file

I have a function that I use on two different machine one a Mac running Python version 2.6 and the other is a Lenovo running version 3.2.The function writes data to a file and is called from with in a loop. When using Python 3.2 it works as expected and I get output such as below

```
25.0    25.0    25.0    0
25.0    25.0    75.0    0
25.0    25.0    125.0   0
25.0    25.0    175.0   0
25.0    25.0    225.0   0
25.0    75.0    25.0    0
25.0    75.0    75.0    0
25.0    75.0    125.0   0
25.0    75.0    175.0   0
25.0    75.0    225.0   0
```

When I run it on the machine running version 2.6 I get this

```
175.0   25.0    75.0    2
175.0   25.0    125.0   0
25.0    25.0    25.0    0   Should be first line
175.0   25.0    175.0   0
25.0    25.0    75.0    0   Should be second line
175.0   25.0    225.0   0   
25.0    25.0    125.0   1
175.0   75.0    25.0    0
25.0    25.0    175.0   1
175.0   75.0    75.0    2
```

Here is the code

```
def filesave(Xc,Yc,Zc,S): 
 Xc = str(Xc)
 Yc = str(Yc)
 Zc = str(Zc)
 Xs = str(S)
 #Ms = str(Ma)   
 w = open("Myout.txt.","a+")
 w.write(Xc)
 w.write('\t')
 w.write(Yc)
 w.write('\t')
 w.write(Zc)
 w.write('\t')
 w.write(Xs)
 w.write('\n')
 w.close()
 return()
```

Is there some difference between the two versions that is causing the difference? Thanks!

**EDIT**

Rest of Code

```
def cell_centers():
 read_file(F)
 dx = dy = dz= float(input('Please enter a value for dr:'))    #length of cell side 
 N  = int(input('Please enter a value for N:')) #N^3 Number of cells to be created
 Xc = zeros(N)       #array creation
 Yc = zeros(N)
 Zc = zeros(N)
 x1=0
 y1=0
 z1=0
 county = 0
 countz = 0

 for i in range(N):          #for loops to define cell centers
    Xc[i] = dx/2 +x1                  
    xmin = Xc[i]-dx/2
    xmax = Xc[i]+dx/2
    x1+=dx                   #increments x1 positions by dx
    for j in range(N):
      Yc[j] = dy/2 +y1
      ymin = Yc[j]-dy/2
      ymax = Yc[j]+dy/2
      county+=1
      if county==N:          #if else statement resets y1 to zero
        y1=0
        county=0
      else:
        y1+=dy
      for k in range(N):
         Zc[k] = dz/2 +z1
         countz+=1
         zmin = Zc[k]-dz/2
         zmax = Zc[k]+dz/2
         if countz==N:
          z1=0   
          countz=0
         else:
          z1+=dz
         counter(Xc[i],Yc[j],Zc[k],N,xmin,xmax,ymin,ymax,zmin,zmax,*read_file(F))

 return()        



def counter(Xc,Yc,Zc,N,xmin,xmax,ymin,ymax,zmin,zmax,Xa,Ya,Za):
 Cellcount = zeros(1)   
 S = (((xmin <= Xa) & (Xa <= xmax))& #count what is in specific range
     ((ymin <= Ya) & (Ya <= ymax))&
     ((zmin <= Za) & (Za <= zmax))).sum()

 for l in range(1):
   Cellcount[l]= S
 filesave(Xc,Yc,Zc,S)
 return()
```

Comment: Could you show the rest of the code, there has to be a loop calling `filesave()`, no? and various parameters? Or can you reproduce this problem with a single set of input?

Comment: Is the problem that the order of lines is wrong? In that case we really ought to see the enclosing loop. It would be helpful if you could clarify the question a bit more. I just called the function with 2.6.5 (Linux), 2.7.2 (Win 7) and 3.2.3 (Win 7) and got identical output, so I don't think write is the problem here, but rather the control structure used to call the function.

Comment: @Levon I added the loop and the function that calls the `filesave()`

Comment: @Levon yes the problem is that the order of the lines is wrong.

Comment: Thanks for posting the additional code, there are still unknown inputs. I don't think the problem is with `filesave`. Can you reproduce this problem with a smaller piece of code and fixed (i.e., hardcoded) inputs? That would be one way to find the cause of your problem. Also, consider the potential problem of division as a cause (**so perhaps the lines aren't out of order, but the results are different due to the division** making it appear that way)

Comment: The output is not out of order, but different (see column 4)

Comment: why don't you print the results to stdout instead of writing to a file and see what you'll get ?

Comment: @Amr I printed the results as you suggested and they matched what I get from version 3.2

Comment: weird, add a global variable `line_count = 0`, increment it and print it with each line and see the order

Comment: @Amr got it working. Think the problem was with the division, but the corrected code did not get properly scp'ed over to the other machine until I added the print statement . Thank you

Comment: I don't think it had anything to do with division, since the argument you're passing (50?) is not an odd number, so, the result of the division shouldn't vary. Glad it's fixed anyway :)

Comment: @Amr that's true. Its still strange that is working now

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am going to go out on the limb and say *the difference you are observing is due to the changed division between version 2.x and 3.x.* (it looks like there's a lot of dividing going on, and I can't tell what type the numbers are, integer or float)

In 2.x you would get integer truncation when doing division with *integers*. This doesn't happen in v 3.x

**Python 2**

```
In [267]: 5 / 2
Out[267]: 2
```

**Python 3:**

```
In [1]: 5 / 2
Out[1]: 2.5
```

Your code does a lot of division.

If you still want to ***old*** integer division behavior, you can use `//` with Python 3:

**Python 3:**

```
In [2]: 5 // 2
Out[2]: 2
```

[Changing the Division Operator](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0238/) explains this in detail.

[What’s New In Python 3.0](http://docs.python.org/release/3.0.1/whatsnew/3.0.html) goes over the big changes from v 2 to 3

If you want the ***new*** division behavior in Python 2.2+, you can use the `from __future__ import division` directive (Thanks @Jeff for reminding me).

**Python 2:**

```
In [1]: 5 / 2
Out[1]: 2

In [2]: from __future__ import division

In [3]: 5 / 2
Out[3]: 2.5
```

**UPDATE**:

Finally, please consider the potential problem of division as a cause (*so perhaps the lines aren't out of order, but the results are different due to the division making it only appear that way*). Is that possible? Also notice that the 4th column (the 3.x output) has all zeros .. that's not present in the 2.x output and further points toward possible problems with the computation of results -- so in fact the results are *different* and not out of order.

Comment: @KirkStrauser I got lucky (for once :-)

Comment: Levon why would the change in the way 2.x and 3.x handle division affect the ordering of the output? I have also changed all of the `dx/2` to `dx/2.0` and still have the ordering problem

Comment: @Surfcast23 actually, I don't think the lines are getting output in different order. I think it's more likely results are being computed differently making it appear that the output is out of order.

Comment: @Surfcast23 Also notice that the 4th column (the 3.x output) has all zeros .. that's not present in the 2.x output and further points toward possible problems with the computation of results.

Comment: @Levon the zeros in the 4th column are because I changed a parameter in the function that reads in the data to speed the code up for trouble shooting. If I change it back I get the values in the 4th columns

Comment: @Levon I think you were correct about the division. When I changed the code to print in the terminal and then scp'ed it over to the mac it started to work so I think that when I originally changed the `dx/2` to `dx/2.0` it may not have scp'ed over properly. It is now working properly thanks for the help

Comment: Maybe mention that you can handle this with `from __future__ import division`?

Comment: @Jeff Thanks for reminding me, that's a good suggestion, I'll update the answer accordingly.

Comment: @Surfcast23 Happy we figured it out, it just seemed the most likely cause. By the way, as an aside, if you are going to be working with Python 3 it would be worth your while to read the "What's new in Python 3" document I linked to in my answer. Until about 2 weeks ago I was only using Python 2.x,  I have since started to also use Python 3 since that is where the language is and the version that will be developed further.

Comment: @Levon it never occurred to me to read the "Whats new Docs" as I have only ever used Python 3.x on my machine, but I will go through it so I will up to speed when using the other machine. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

Your `filesave` function is fine. I bet the difference in output is because Python 2 returns an integer from integer division expressions, while Python 3 returns a float:

### Python 2

```
>>> 1/2
0
>>> 4/2
2
```

### Python 3

```
>>> 1/2
0.5
>>> 4/2
2.0
```

This will give different mathematical results in your program and might account for the different ordering of the output.